# Does Google Play have some APIs for get some information for apps?

Tags: google-play

iTunes provides an API `http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=337254112` which have some useful information suck like `genre`, `primaryGenre` ... Is Google Play have some APIs like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out these links:

Commercial: https://droidmeter.com

Open Source: https://github.com/chadrem/market_bot

http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

http://github.com/kanzure/android-market-api-py